# SwiftUI Charts .foregroundStyle - Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swiftui, charts

I'm in a Catch22 when constructing the .foregroundStyle. If I don't optionalise it it runs but then give the "Optional value" error and crashes to @main. If I do optionalise it it gives the "var body: some View/Unable to type check in reasonable time" error. I am clearly doing something wrong...

My data is structured like:

```
 @State var monthlyOutput = [
    (chartline:"Daylight", data: [
        WeatherData(month:"Jan", value: 0.0),
        WeatherData(month:"Feb", value: 0.0),
        WeatherData(month:"Mar", value: 0.0),
        ...
        WeatherData(month:"Dec", value: 0.0),
    ]),
    
    (chartline:"Sunrise", data: [
        WeatherData(month:"Jan", value: 0.0),
        WeatherData(month:"Feb", value: 0.0),
        WeatherData(month:"Mar", value: 0.0),
        ...
        WeatherData(month:"Dec", value: 0.0),
    ])
 ]
```

The charts are drawn with:

```
Chart() {
                ForEach(monthlyOutput, id: \.chartline) { chartlineData in
                    ForEach(chartlineData.data) { weather in
                        LineMark(
                            x: .value("Month", weather.month),
                            y: .value("X", weather.value)
                        )
                        .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
                        .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: chartlineData.chartline==literals[selectedChartline].0 ? 3.0 : 2.0))
                        .foregroundStyle(by: .value("chartline", chartlineData.chartline?))
                    }
                }
            }
```

If I rem out the .foregroundStyle line the problem goes away but have several charts all drawn in the same colour ;-).

Comment: Why is monthlyOutput an @State property, will it change while the chart is showing? I’m asking because if you remove that property wrapper your code will work fine if you also remove the ?

Comment: These are the start values and then later on various calculations are done that generate the filled charts. These calculations take time otherwise they would be done beforehand.

Comment: I just ran you code again in a playground, using @State, and for me foregroundStyle works fine with a non optional value. I believe the issue is not with the posted code alone.

Comment: If I rem out the .foregroundStyle line then it works, albeit in one colour, e.g. // .foregroundStyle(by: .value("chartline", chartlineData.month?)) If I include it crashes to @main. On my system this line seems to be the culprit. I'll continue investigating. With many thanks for your help.